# SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces error 259 for display

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to retrieve a set of display related interfaces and seem always to get the 259 error. Since I am very unexperienced with `WinApi` I could need some hints :)

```
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <SetupApi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "setupapi.lib") 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <devguid.h>

#include <regstr.h>

const GUID GUID_CLASS_MONITOR = {0x4d36e96e, 0xe325, 0x11ce, 0xbf, 0xc1, 0x08, 0x00, 0x2b, 0xe1, 0x03, 0x18};
const GUID GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR = {0xe6f07b5f, 0xee97, 0x4a90, 0xb0, 0x76, 0x33, 0xf5, 0x7b, 0xf4, 0xea, 0xa7};
int main( int argc, char *argv[ ] )
{

    HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA ifData;
    ifData.cbSize = sizeof(ifData);
    DWORD dwError;

    hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL /*&GUID_CLASS_MONITOR*/, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_ALLCLASSES);

    dwError = GetLastError(); 

    BOOL bRtn = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDevInfo, NULL, &GUID_CLASS_MONITOR, 0, &ifData);  // GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR did not work either

    dwError = GetLastError(); 
    return 0;
}
```

I cannot see what I am doing wrong `SetupDiGetClassDevs` has no errors but everything I try regarding `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces` returns **259**.
I've been trying both device setup as well the device interface GUID with no luck.

Edit: Clarification: bRtn returns 0 which means that `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces` has failed. The `259` error means no more items but my system has two screens attached and since I am calling `SetupDiGetClassDevs` with no GUID I have expected to get at least my two screen items.

Edit: Added cbSize as suggested

Comment: You know that `GetLastError` is only valid if `bRtn` is `FALSE`?

Comment: [ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) (PS. I think I see your error... but I'm late for work.   Details later...)

Comment: Don't get me wrong. bRtn is always 0 and I get the 259 no more items. I am aware of that but since I have 2 displays attached to my pc I expect to see more data. I do not understand where my mistake is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the answer I found by try and error is not intuitive for me but it seems to work.

As I am unable to retrieve the device setup GUID but I had to add `DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE` with conjunction to device interface GUID `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR` to be able to retrieve the interfaces.

Thanks for the hints as missing cbSize would have resulted in another error too :/

Answer (score 2):

Do you know that `ifData.cbSize` must be set properly before you call `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces`?

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551015(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The caller must set DeviceInterfaceData.cbSize to sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA) before calling this function.

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552342(v=vs.85).aspx)

> A SetupAPI function that takes an instance of the SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA structure as a parameter verifies whether the cbSize member of the supplied structure is equal to the size, in bytes, of the structure.

You did not show setting this value in your code.

Comment: I've added it to my sample code to be as compilable as possible. I did indeed forgot that but it has no effect on the outcome. The code above without the sizeof is a copy paste from http://www.pixcl.com/SetupDiEnumInterfaces_Fail.htm which skipped the size part. Thanks for the hint but that was not the main issue here.